# Do I need to destroy icon after I added it to ImageList?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, mfc, icons

I'm loading my icons using [LoadIconWithScaleDown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775703%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API (or using [LoadImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648045%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for XP.) I then add it to my CImageList as such:

```
//CImageList imgList;
//HICON hIcon = loaded with LoadIconWithScaleDown
imgList.Add(hIcon);

//Is the following line needed?
::DestroyIcon(hIcon);
```

I see contradicting statements about whether or not I should free the icon after it's added to my image list.

The documentation for [CImageList::Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4z9sc5dx.aspx) says:

> You are responsible for releasing the icon handle when you are done
>   with it.

But the documentation for [ImageList_ReplaceIcon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775215%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that CImageList::Add calls internally says:

> You do not need to destroy hicon if it was loaded by the LoadIcon
>   function; the system automatically frees an icon resource when it is
>   no longer needed.

Well, I did not exactly load it with [LoadIcon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648072%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (which is deprecated.) So what shall I do?

Comment: Yes, you need to delete the icon - the imagelist simply copies the image data into its internal storage, it doesn't keep a record of the icon handle. Icons loaded via LoadIcon from your program's resources do not *need* to be deleted because the system can reclaim their resources automatically, however it's still good practice to do so.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: As I said, I'm not using LoadIcon per se, I load them via LoadIconWithScaleDown or LoadImage.

Comment: As I said, *Yes, you need to delete the icon*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No function related to image lists will ever destroy an icon automatically. That is because the owner of the icon needs to decide whether or not to destroy it. This information can be found in the documentation for [`DestroyIcon`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648063.aspx) where you are told not to use `DestroyIcon` with shared icons:

> It is only necessary to call DestroyIcon for icons and cursors created with the following functions: CreateIconFromResourceEx (if called without the LR_SHARED flag), CreateIconIndirect, and CopyIcon. Do not use this function to destroy a shared icon. A shared icon is valid as long as the module from which it was loaded remains in memory. The following functions obtain a shared icon.
>
> - LoadIcon
> - LoadImage (if you use the LR_SHARED flag)
> - CopyImage (if you use the LR_COPYRETURNORG flag and the hImage parameter is a shared icon)
> - CreateIconFromResource
> - CreateIconFromResourceEx (if you use the LR_SHARED flag)

This effectively puts the onus on the application programmer to keep track of whether or not `DestroyIcon` is needed. And so other API functions simply will never call `DestroyIcon`.

The documentation from `ImageList_ReplaceIcon` that you refer to is simply repeating the advice that I quote above.

Image lists don't actually hold icons. They hold rectangular bitmaps with the images tiled. So they make a copy of the image that you provide. As a general rule, an API function will never require you to keep a parameter alive after the function returns without that requirement being explicitly documented. And what's more, such a requirement would be onerous on the caller, and a good API would never put such a requirement on the caller if it can be readily avoided.

Comment: Thanks. The issue is what `ImageList_ReplaceIcon` does with the icon that I pass to it. If it makes a "deep" copy that is independent of mine, then yes, I can safely destroy mine asap. But if it merely creates a reference to my icon, then destroying my icon immediately will create an obvious problem. That was not clear for me from that scarce MSDN documentation.

Comment: Image lists don't store icons. They store rectangular bitmaps that hold all the images. Anyway, as I said, no API ever calls DestroyIcon on an icon that you pass it.

Comment: So like @JonathanPotter concluded, I can destroy my icon right after `imgList.Add(hIcon);` call, right?

Comment: Er yes. That's what I mean. No api will do it for you, ergo you have to do it.

Comment: Yes, I get it. But what I'm saying is if the image list doesn't make a "deep" copy of my icon I cannot destroy it immediately and have to keep it "alive" for as long as the image list is used.

Comment: The image list does copy the content of the icon. As a general rule, if an api requires you to keep something alive after the function returns, that requirement will be explicitly called out.

Comment: "As a general rule" is a tricky business with MS. But, anyway, thanks. I got it.

Comment: Actually the Windows API is pretty well designed in this regard. It really does adhere to that rule.